# How do I retry an Flux invoker?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

In case of resilience i am trying to simulate a database breakdown.

```
  public void createParticipationCheckWorkflowsForThis(Integer numberOfAdvices) {
    participationAdviceSource.getParticipationAdvicesByAMaximumLimitOf(numberOfAdvices) // i want to retry this
        .subscribe(participationAdviceSender::sendAdviceToWorkflowEngine);
  }
```

My test scenario specifies that on the first database call, which is using Spring-R2DBC i return a flux error and on its second call a correct result.

```
when(participationAdviceSource.getParticipationAdvicesByAMaximumLimitOf(anyInt()))
    .thenReturn(Flux.error(new RuntimeException()))
    .thenReturn(Flux.just(ParticipationAdvice.builder().participationId(1L).build()));
```

My specific question is how can i retry the invoker/producer, because the retry mechanism of reactive retries the subscribe not the producer

Answer (score 2):

You can use `retry` or `retryWhen` along with the [Retry API](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/util/retry/Retry.html):

```java
 Flux.defer(() -> participationAdviceSource.getParticipationAdvicesByAMaximumLimitOf(numberOfAdvices))
    .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(retryMaxAttempts, Duration.ofMillis(retryMinBackoff)).maxBackoff(Duration.ofMillis(retryMaxBackoff)))
```

A `Flux.defer` wrapper is required because `retry` and `retryWhen` work by re-subscribing to the `Flux` (if the `Flux` throws an error and the retry conditions are fulfilled).